# Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource ElasticIPAddress(AWS CLoudformation)

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-vpc, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource, aws-nat-gateway

I am trying to deploy VPC, subnets etc but I am getting the above error. I am not sure why I am getting this error.
Here is the part of the template(yml) file where I am getting this error.

```
  NATGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
     AllocationId: !GetAtt ElasticIPAddress.AllocationId
     SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnetA
     Tags:
     - Key: Name
       Value: !Sub NAT-${AWS::StackName}
```

thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have a resource called `ElasticIPAddress` ? ...

Comment: No, It's not defined anywhere in the template. 
How can I get AllocationId then?

Comment: `!GetAtt` is used to *reference* another resource in the template. you cannot reference a non-existing resource which is why you are getting the error. If you want to create an Elastic IP Address, then you need to add that to your template https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip.html

Comment: After Adding this
 ** ElasticIPAddress:
    DependsOn: AttachGateway
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: VPC**
it worked, Thanks @Paolo